# turn off auto-quotes in web-mode

Tags: web-mode

Currently I have jsx in my js files but when using web-mode it is only possible to have single quotes or double quotes for html attributes with this setting the `web-mode-auto-quote-style` setting, e.g:

```
(setq web-mode-auto-quote-style 2) ; use single quotes
```

I would like to disable it all together but how is this possible when it only takes 1 or 2 as a value.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
(setq web-mode-enable-auto-quoting nil)
```

> Add double quotes after the character = in a tag.